# Prove how the algorithm works

Tags: algorithms, proof-writing

Given the pseudocode

```
MUL(a,b) 
   x=a
   y=0
   WHILE x>=b DO
      x=x-b
      y=y+1
   IF x=0 THEN
      RETURN(true)
   ELSE
      RETURN(false)
```

I have to prove how the algorithm works.

So far I have only *explained* how it works, but I am not sure how you are supposed to *prove* how it works.

What I am looking for is simply an explanation as to what I am asked to do since I can't seem to figure it out myself. Personally I would just explain what the algorithm does, but I have done that in a previous question and am now asked to prove the algorithm.

Comment: You might want to expect what it is supposed to do and what the restrictions are on $a,b$.

Comment: @copper.hat But again isn't that the explanation of how it works (i.e. what it does and the restriction) and not the proof of how it works?

Comment: Write a loop invariant. Prove that the loop terminates. Standard stuff.

Comment: It shouldn't  be called `MUL`. It should be called a `DIV`. Because that's what it does: division.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a,b$ are positive numbers and $a\ge b$ then the program tests if $a$ is a multiple of $b$ (that is, $\frac{a}{b}$ is a positive integer.) How? Note that it is getting $a,a-b,a-2b,\cdots$ It stops when $a-nb<b.$ If $a-nb=0$ then it returns "true" (that is, $a$ is a multiple of $b$.) In other case "false".

If $a<b$ then it returns "false" (assuming again that $a,b$ are positive numbers).

Answer (score 0):

this program divide $a$ by $b$.

if you divide $a$ by $b$, you will have $y$ as a quotient and $x$ as the remainder.

$y$ counts how many $b$ are in $[0,a]$.

Answer (score 0):

A suitable loop invariant is $a=x+ yb$. This is true at the start and end
of each iteration of the while loop.

Since $x$ after the loop is strictly smaller that $x$ at the start of the
loop, it **must** terminate in a finite number of steps with $x < b$ (and
implicitly, $b \ge 0$).

Hence the final $x$ is the remainder of dividing $a$ by $b$.

Then $b \mid a$ **iff** the returned value is zero.